# Asynchronous call not working

Tags: angular

In the ngInit function of my BrandComponent class I am making an asynchronous call to the filterProduct() function of my BrandService object.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.brandSidebarService.sidebarData$.subscribe(sidebarData => {
      this.brandService.filterProducts(sidebarData).subscribe(products => {
        this.products = products;
      })
    })
  }
```

This is the filterProducts() function of the BrandService class:

```
public filterProducts(productFilters) {
    this.dataService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      let filteredProducts = products;
      filteredProducts = this.filterByBrands(productFilters[0], 
         filteredProducts);
      filteredProducts = this.filterByPrices(productFilters[1], 
         filteredProducts);
      filteredProducts = this.filterByRating(productFilters[2], 
          filteredProducts);  

      return of(filteredProducts);
    })
  }
```

In the BrandComponent ngInit function I am getting the following error from the subscription shown below even though filterProducts() of BrandService returns an observable.

```
this.brandService.filterProducts(sidebarData).subscribe(products...

[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already subscribed to the Observable ( *`this.dataService.getProducts()` result* ) which is returned from the `filterProducts`. If you want an extra job to do with the result data, you can just `pipe` to `getProducts` function and add extra mapper ( `map` ), which maps the result.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public filterProducts(productFilters) {
    return this.dataService.getProducts().pipe(
       map(products => {
             let filteredProducts = products;
             filteredProducts = this.filterByBrands(productFilters[0], filteredProducts);
             filteredProducts = this.filterByPrices(productFilters[1], filteredProducts);
             filteredProducts = this.filterByRating(productFilters[2], filteredProducts);  

             return filteredProducts;
       })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the error doesn't match the code you posted. It complains about `subscribe`not existing in the type `Subscription`, but your method doesn't actually return a Subscription. It returns nothing (i.e. `undefined`).

Don't subscribe. Use the `map` operator to transform the observable of something into an observable of something else. Note that you're not specifying types anywhere, thus preventing TypeScript to discover errors at compile-time, and thus shooting yourself in the foot. So I'll use made-up types here, since I don't know what they actually are:

```
public filterProducts(productFilters: Array<ProductFilter>): Observable<Product> {
  // note the return keyword on the next line, which is necessary for your method to return something

  return this.dataService.getProducts().pipe(
    map(products => {
      let filteredProducts = products;
      filteredProducts = this.filterByBrands(productFilters[0], filteredProducts);
      filteredProducts = this.filterByPrices(productFilters[1], filteredProducts);
      filteredProducts = this.filterByRating(productFilters[2], filteredProducts);  

      return filteredProducts;
    })
  );
}
```